# Swift 3 Data in post request is not submitted when content-type is setted

Tags: json, swift, post, swift3

I'm currently trying to make a post request from my app to my rest-service.

[image: Following image shows my code]

Now, when I don't set the Content-Type value to the request, my rest-service gets the data, but not as json. 
I thought, setting the content-type header would be the solution, but when its setted, my rest-service receives NO data. (But the header is correctly setted with "application/json ..." 
I'm new to swift and I'm wondering if someone could help me to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post code as a picture. [Edit] your question and replace the picture with your actual code, as text, copied and pasted. Pictures of code can't be searched or referenced.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the web service is expecting JSON and that your supplied JSON is of the correct format?

Comment: Unrelated, don't use `NSMutableURLRequest`. Do `var request = URLRequest(url: url!)`, and then the cast to `URLRequest` will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Alamofire for networking requests in Swift. Also if your dealing with JSON data I would use the SwiftyJSON library. Then you can make networking requests like this:

```
//start activity indicator here

    Alamofire.request("https://urlhere.com" , method: .post).validate().responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success(let value):

              if let json = JSON(value) {

               let name = json["name"].stringValue

                //hide activity indicator here

               }
               else
                {
                 //No data returned
                }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            //show error indicator here

        }

    }
```

If the response comes back within the 200 range, you can run some code and if it comes back anything else it will fail and you can catch any errors there. You can also start and stop an activity indicator in the following code so that the user gets some notice that a background action is taking place.

**Edit:** This all assumes that your web service returns JSON data. I don't have any way to verify but if it does, it should be pretty simple to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

check with your backend Developer if a content type is JSON or plain text

if plain text just use  **text/plain; charset=UTF-8**

you can check this with any poster plugin  check this 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en